# Log4Net TelnetAppender does not run when app runs as windows service

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have an application that uses the rolling log appender and the telnet appender.
The application can run as either a service or a desktop application. When I run as a desktop app the rolling appender and telnet appender both work and I can telnet to the port and see log messages come through. When I run the app as a service the rolling log appender works but the telnet appender does not.

I have tried netstat -nab and see the port when running as a desktop application, but when run as a service telnet fails to connect to the port and the service exe does not appear in the output from netstat.

I tried changing the service logon to my local account to no avail, and I tried turning off the windows firewall.

Below is my configuration if anyone could shed some light on this I would appreciate the help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="rfa" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="my.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="3" />
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-23date{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss fff}  %-8level %-25logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ta" type="log4net.Appender.TelnetAppender">
      <port value="23" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-25date{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss fff} %-8level %-25logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="rfa" />
      <appender-ref ref="ta" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```